# HTML Checkbox says that it is checked/unchecked but it is not

Tags: jquery

```
if($(this).prop('checked', true)){
    $(this).prop('checked',false);
        console.log('its checked yo');
    } else if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
        $('[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        console.log("Well this certainly isn't checked");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkj8n/2/#run
So my setup is for a form that adds pricing for different options you select with a checkbox.  For this group of items only one option can be selected at a time.  So when another item gets selected I uncheck all boxes and then check the one that they pick.  I have tried this using .prop() .attr() and more and it hasn't worked.  One of three things happens every time.

1. It works and I can only pick one and the others are deselected.  BUT:  I cannot uncheck that item, and the prices (values) for the other checkboxes are added which means that it thinks they are still checked.
2. It says they are all checked no matter what.. even if they aren't.  So nothing works.
3. The values are added correctly.. I'm only getting one option at a time and I can click that option again to set it back to zero.  BUT:  The check mark doesn't show up in the box.

This is frustrating me.  Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but, in the fiddle at least, you check if the checkbox is checked, then immediately set it to unchecked. With that behavior, the checkbox will always be unchecked.

Comment: Nope you're right.  This wasn't the JS fiddle I meant to use though I had the correct logic in another one.  Is there anyway to get rid of my question so I don't feel as stupid?

Comment: There should be an option to delete or remove underneath of it I think. don't feel stupid though. It's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this -

```
if($(this).prop('checked')){
```

What you are using is a `setter` *not a `getter`*

- http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: He uses the getter in the fiddle. His logic is bad. He's doing: on change, if checkbox checked, uncheck checkbox. Therefore, checkbox will ALWAYS be unchecked.

Comment: I swear I had the getter earlier <.< Now I feel pretty stupid but that's ok it works now thanks a lot!